# Retreiving specific data from JSON repsonse only in certain array indexes

Tags: javascript, json, api

Hey sorry if this has been asked before, I haven't found an answer that has helped me.

I am working on building a personal application using the free Ticketmaster application but I'm having trouble with the JSON response.

An example of the response is:

```
data: {
    classifications: [
      type: {
         id: 1,
         name: "Dont want this"
      }
    ],
    [
      type: {
         id: 2,
         name: "Dont want this"
      }
    ],
    [
       category: {
         id: 3,
         name: "Food & Drink"
       }
    ],
    [
       category: {
          id: 4,
          name: "Music"
    ]
}
```

I am trying to retrieve category names such as "Family", "Food & Drink", "Music" etc but only at some indexes does the array have category objects, the others have type.

Can someone tell me how to go through this array and only get the name when it is at category.name?

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think that the first problem is that your response is not a Json valid

Comment: Did you mean this http://www.mocky.io/v2/5ea0aef53200006f0094b0fd ?

Comment: I don't create the json sorry its just an example of the response I receive from an api. I'm trying to get segment and not type

Comment: ah okay. can you give the api url?

Comment: This is the link: https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/classifications.json?apikey={{apikey}}

Comment: I have folllowed this https://developer.ticketmaster.com/products-and-docs/apis/discovery-api/v2/#anchor_find and it return a valid json. The category key is not the same as in your post

Comment: Can you past your request JSON response in  mocky.io a send the link?

Comment: @balzacLeGeek It was just an example but in the correct json it returns it is segment, not category. It wont let me post it into mocky.io perhaps because the response is so huge.